# Association model

Tags: extjs4

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
Ext.apply.urlAppend ext-all-debug.js:5040
Ext.define.buildUrl ext-all-debug.js:26324
Ext.define.buildRequest ext-all-debug.js:26148
Ext.define.doRequest ext-all-debug.js:26367
Ext.define.read ext-all-debug.js:26117
Ext.define.inheritableStatics.load ext-all-debug.js:26603
(anonymous function) ext-all-debug.js:51162
(anonymous function) test.html:89
isEvent ext-all-debug.js:10117
call ext-all-debug.js:10073
```

I don't know what is worry. I have checked the instance structure in FF and it really has the function getCategory.
Thanks!

```
        Ext.define("Category", {
            extend: "Ext.data.Model",
            fields: ["id", "name"]
        });
        Ext.define("Product", {
            extend: "Ext.data.Model",
            fields: ["id", "name", "category_id"],
            associations: [{
                type: "belongsTo",
                model: "Category",
                primaryKey: "id",
                foreignKey: "category_id",
                associationKey: "category"
            }]
        });

        Ext.onReady(function(){
            var p = new Product({
                id: 1,
                name: "Kotomi",
                category_id: 2,
                category: {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Clannad"
                }
            });
            console.log(p.getCategory().get("name"));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample from [documentation of ExtJs 4](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.BelongsToAssociation). You have missleaded the sentences bellow:

```
The getCategory function was created on the Product model when we defined the 
association. This uses the Category's configured proxy  to load the Category
asynchronously, calling the provided callback when it has loaded.
```

So, this error is because of missing **proxy** config in Category model.